# Display google maps with different latitude and longitude in two div class

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I want to show two google maps having different latitude and longitude in two div class. For displaying google map I have used same script,but I have changed lat long coordinate in script.I have two div class having different class name and call scripts.But I am only getting only one map.Here is my code

```
<div class="section s5">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-right-1">
        <h1>Find me at-</h1>
        <p><strong>MOHAMMAD IMRAN</strong><br>
        F-18/22 Second Floor <br>
        Jogabai Extn, Batla House<br>
        New Delhi-110025<br>
        Mobile No- +91 9582307425<br>
        Email: mohd.imran980@gmail.com</p>
            <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:270px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:300px;width:270px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='http://www.quotes.as/'>Quotes.as</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=2a4ab4f7bff1a5593997160db587449f2e987dcb'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(31.6963654,75.45983739999997),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(31.6963654,75.45983739999997)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>New Delhi</strong><br>F-18/22 Batla House<br>110025 New Delhi<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
        </div>



        <div class="contact-right-2">
        <h1>Find also me at-</h1>
        <p>MOHAMMAD IMRAN<br>
        97/170 Readymade Beconganj <br>
        Kanpur-110025<br>
        Mobile No- +91 9582307425<br>
        Tele: 011-93532363<br>
        Email: mohd.imran980@gmail.com</p>
    <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:270px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:300px;width:270px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='http://www.quotes.as/'>Quotes.as</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=4299b549b28f8bb7b8e338657ffb40a26a4276c2'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(26.4679038,80.3411542),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.4679038,80.3411542)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Kanpur</strong><br>97/171 Beconganj Kanpur<br>208001 kanpur<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
        </div>
```

Please somebody help..

Comment: I think ID name is same ,please change ID name then you got,

Comment: Thanks...It works as a charm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check it,in your code ID is same so its not working but here I have change it

```
<div class="section s5">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-right-1">
        <h1>Find me at-</h1>
        <p><strong>MOHAMMAD IMRAN</strong><br>
        F-18/22 Second Floor <br>
        Jogabai Extn, Batla House<br>
        New Delhi-110025<br>
        Mobile No- +91 9582307425<br>
        Email: mohd.imran980@gmail.com</p>
            <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>
            <div style='overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:270px;'>
            <div id='gmap_canvas2' style='height:300px;width:270px;'>
            </div>

            </div> 
            <a href='http://www.quotes.as/'>Quotes.as</a> 
            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=2a4ab4f7bff1a5593997160db587449f2e987dcb'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(31.6963654,75.45983739999997),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas2'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(31.6963654,75.45983739999997)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>New Delhi</strong><br>F-18/22 Batla House<br>110025 New Delhi<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
            </script>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-right-2">
        <h1>Find also me at-</h1>
        <p>MOHAMMAD IMRAN<br>
        97/170 Readymade Beconganj <br>
        Kanpur-110025<br>
        Mobile No- +91 9582307425<br>
        Tele: 011-93532363<br>
        Email: mohd.imran980@gmail.com</p>
    <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:270px;'><div id='gmap_canvas1' style='height:300px;width:270px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas1 img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='http://www.quotes.as/'>Quotes.as</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=4299b549b28f8bb7b8e338657ffb40a26a4276c2'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(26.4679038,80.3411542),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas1'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.4679038,80.3411542)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Kanpur</strong><br>97/171 Beconganj Kanpur<br>208001 kanpur<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
        </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make as less changes as possible in your original code, so that you can see the root cause of the issues.

The changes I've made:

- Change the id of second map canvas to gmap_canvas2, and change the name of second init function to init_map2
- Google map script and the script from embedmaps.com were referenced twice, I've combined them together and move them to the beginning.

Two maps show up after these 2 changes.

You will notice the message "Google Maps Error: Do not change the code. Click here to show the correct code!" when running the code snippet, you may follow the link to find out how to improve myOptions object.

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=2a4ab4f7bff1a5593997160db587449f2e987dcb'></script>
<div class="section s5">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-right-1">
        <h1>Find me at-</h1>
        <p><strong>MOHAMMAD IMRAN</strong><br>
        F-18/22 Second Floor <br>
        Jogabai Extn, Batla House<br>
        New Delhi-110025<br>
        Mobile No- +91 9582307425<br>
        Email: mohd.imran980@gmail.com</p>
            <div style='overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:270px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:300px;width:270px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='http://www.quotes.as/'>Quotes.as</a><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(31.6963654,75.45983739999997),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(31.6963654,75.45983739999997)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>New Delhi</strong><br>F-18/22 Batla House<br>110025 New Delhi<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
        </div>



        <div class="contact-right-2">
        <h1>Find also me at-</h1>
        <p>MOHAMMAD IMRAN<br>
        97/170 Readymade Beconganj <br>
        Kanpur-110025<br>
        Mobile No- +91 9582307425<br>
        Tele: 011-93532363<br>
        Email: mohd.imran980@gmail.com</p>
    <div style='overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:270px;'><div id='gmap_canvas2' style='height:300px;width:270px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='http://www.quotes.as/'>Quotes.as</a><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map2(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(26.4679038,80.3411542),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas2'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.4679038,80.3411542)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Kanpur</strong><br>97/171 Beconganj Kanpur<br>208001 kanpur<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map2);</script>
        </div>
</div></div>
```